# Stop character jump height from changing based on frame rate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've written a function for my character controller to allow the player character to perform a jump action. I am using two monitors at the moment, one is a 60hz display while the pther is a 120hz display. When running the game on the 120hz display, the jump function acts as I expect it to, but when running on the 60hz display, the character jumps way higher than I intended. I know this has something to do with using Time.deltatime, but I can't figure out how to implement it properly into my jump function. the code is as follows:

```
 void PlayerJump()
{


    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {   
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpForce;          

            }
        else
            {
                moveDirection.y = fallSpeed;

            }
    }
     moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y  + (Physics.gravity.y ) ;

}
```

here's everything above the previous function for further clarification:

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class platforming_controller_2D : MonoBehaviour
 {

public float movementSpeed;
public float jumpForce;
public float gravityScale;
public float fallSpeed;





public double jumpGravity = (-9.81 * 0.045);


public Animator anim;
public CharacterController controller;

private Vector3 moveDirection;

void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void Update()
{
    PlayerMovement();
    playRunAnimation();
    PlayerJump();
    playJumpAnimation();
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}

void PlayerMovement()
{
    //float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed, moveDirection.y, 0.0f);
    transform.LookAt(newPosition + transform.position);
}
```

Comment: Need more information -- how is moveDirection.y being used?

Comment: If it uses Unity's physics, put all rigidbody movement/jumping in FixedUpdate().